# How to add random string to Azure Function Blob Output file name? - The specified block list is invalid

Tags: azure-functions

I have Blob output working successfully when java function is invoked in non fast cycle.
But getting error when function are invoked in fast cycle. Since durable singleton are not supported in Java, I just have to make that each file have unique name.

How to add random string or guid to name so that each file get unique name even timestamp is same.

ERROR:

```
system.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.TopicTriggerDatalakeOutput. 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error while handling parameter _binder after function returned:. 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The specified block list is invalid.
```

CODE:

```
@BlobOutput(
         name = "target", 
        connection = "DataLakeConnString",
        path = "profile/blob_{DateTime}.csv")
        OutputBinding<String> outputItem,
```

Comment: Hi, have you try my answer? Any update?

Answer (score 0):

The blob name provided in the Java-based Azure Function declaration section must be a constant, so if you want to add a random GUID to the blob directly in the binding, it is impossible.

But your idea can still be realized, just put the logic inside the function, just like this:

```
String connectStr = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
String containerName = "yourcontainername";
String fileName = "yourblobprefix" + java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + ".txt";
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.createBlobContainer(containerName);
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);
long streamlong = request.getBody().get().length();
String st = request.getBody().get();
InputStream inputstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(st.getBytes());
blobClient.upload(inputstream, streamlong, true);
```

You can have a look of this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java#upload-blobs-to-a-container). It tells you how to upload blob and it is based on java v12 sdk. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java-legacy) is about java sdk v8.